# Error when trying to linking libcurl in static

Tags: c++, static, linker-errors, libcurl, static-linking

I'm new in C++ and I got a problem about linking libcurl in **static**, I downloaded sources and build it myself:

```
./configure && make install
```

Everything is okay, I write my cmake file, build my program and run, it's working, so I try to link in static and I got many errors about **ssl** and **thread**, so I go back in the doc and see that I can build without ssl and thread ( https://curl.se/docs/install.html ), I decided to delete previous installation and rebuild with the next command:

```
./configure --without-ssl --disable-thread && make install
```

In dynamic linking it's working but same problem in static... and I just cannot find a way to solve the problem.
Ine the errors in see "undefined reference to Curl_thread_create" but I built the lib without thread and I included all Curl headers ! I'm lost

Here a picture of my workspace [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFUsa.png)

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please post errors, cmake and other data as text, not a picture with text. Otherwise your question will be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you link your app with the static libcurl.a, you have to link your app with all other libs that would be linked with the dynamic libcurl.so. You need to build and link your app with following flags:

```
target_compile_options($(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME) -pthread)
target_link_libraries($(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME) curl pthread z)
```

Perhaps other flags for the errors not shown in the question are required.